# Problem georeferencing a raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing

I successfully georeferenced the raster the first time and it loaded correctly in QGIS. Then, I went back to the georeferencer to add more control points to make the overlay look more exact. When I ran the georeferencer again the raster loaded into QGIS but the image was unrecognizable and not where it was supposed to be. [image: messed up overlay]

Is it possible to add more control points to a raster that I've already georeferenced?

In the attached image, the brown space is supposed to be the georeferenced raster that should overlay the parcels on the vector layer